# Conditional Google Sheet Checkbox

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, data-validation

I am creating a spreadsheet which can track all of the replacement items I am sending out for my business, however, I also want to be able to track my refunds on the same spreadsheet. I have got it so that a checkbox is conditionally formatted to change the background colour of certain cells to signify if the replacement has been sent out. Is there a way that the conditional formatting can be adapted to have a different colour if a different box says Replacement or Refund. (See attached photos for reference)

[image]

I would like to be able to have a different colour for the cells if the "Replacement/Refund" Field has "refund" in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **custom formula for rule 1:** **`=AND($I2=TRUE, $C2="Refund")`** (green color)
- **custom formula for rule 2:** **`=AND($I2=TRUE, $C2="Replacement")`** (blue color)

[image]